# Rails problems between development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'm dealing with some weird inconsistencies on my production server for my rails website/blog.

For instance, on my development server (just running Webrick) this is my navbar (which is correct) and shows up 100% of the time:

[image]

After pushing my latest code to the production server (passenger & nginx), my navbar now shows (notice the missing blog link) and shows up about 40% of the time.  I have to keep hitting 'refresh' on my browser until the blog link to shows:

[image]

What gives here?  New to RoR, but I believe the issue lies with my Blog MVC.  I've been taking a look at the log files for nginx and they show nothing.

Where else can I go to diagnose this issue?

---

Here is the code in my navbar partial (_navigation.html.erb)

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to("How It Works", "/howto") %></li>
    <li><%= link_to("FAQ", "/frequent") %></li>
    <li><%= link_to("Blog", blogs_path) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to("Contact Us", "/contact_forms/new") %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Tailing production.log isn't very revealing either.  When the 'Blog' link does load:

```
I, [2015-03-31T12:48:59.624208 #5061]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for X.X.X.X at 2015-03-31 12:48:59 -0400
I, [2015-03-31T12:48:59.625722 #5061]  INFO -- : Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
D, [2015-03-31T12:48:59.627223 #5061] DEBUG -- :   Testimonial Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "testimonials".* FROM "testimonials"
I, [2015-03-31T12:48:59.628629 #5061]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.3ms)
I, [2015-03-31T12:48:59.631063 #5061]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
I, [2015-03-31T12:48:59.631303 #5061]  INFO -- :   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
I, [2015-03-31T12:48:59.632149 #5061]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

When the Blog link doesn't load production.log hardly has anything written to it.  It's like the server is only registering a partial load of the page or something.

I've made my changes, rebooted the web server (both nginx & passenger), and even rebooted the actual server itself... still no luck.

I'm at a loss on what to do to fix this issue since everything works perfectly fine in development and I'm still pretty new to RoR.

Comment: Can you show the nav-bar code?

Comment: @AbM just added to original post.

Comment: is there any reason why you don't use rails path helpers?

Comment: @Avdept learning RoR as I go along... just changed the blog path (since that's what I'm focusing on right now) to blogs_path.  I don't see how that would help resolve the issue though.

Comment: That was just question not really related to your problem

Comment: @Avdept No worries, always happy to learn the ruby way.  I did make the change you suggested anyhow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The source code is pretty trivial and there is no conditional branching (`if`) around the blog link.

Therefore, the only explanation is that the code running in production is not the one you have in development.

Make sure your deploy was successful. Inspect your server folder to make sure the code is in there. Also make sure the webserver was restarted, otherwise it may still be serving the previously deployed code. For Passenger and Nginx you need (unless it changed) to `touch` the `restart.txt` file inside the `/tmp/restart.txt` project folder in order to perform a Passenger restart (without obviously restarting the entire Nginx process).

Comment: I'm using `cap deploy` to push my code to the server from my git repo.  It's my understanding that the process restarts nginx/passenger automatically.

Comment: Also just verified that the server is running the same code that is in my development environment.  I did this by changing the blog link in my navigation to `blog_path` and checked the code for my _navigation partial on the server.

Comment: If the code is there, the server was not restarted.

Comment: Tried `sudo service nginx restart`, server restarted, still same inconsistencies with navigation links loading.

Tried `touch /myapp/tmp/restart.txt`, no luck either!

Comment: nginx isnt web server. Nginx is proxying server. You need to restart your web server, which is might be thin, unicorn, puma, webrick. Also check if code updated on server(via console). If no - then capistrano might not using your current branch